# Core Data Not Saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nslog

I have an app that uses the core data framework and I'm fairly new at it. When I type in information about the "pilot" and save it the NSLog for that entity returns null, and I can't figure out why they're not saving any help would be appreciated.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Pilot.h"




@interface PilotViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>







@property (weak, nonatomic       ) IBOutlet UITextField                 *nameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic       ) IBOutlet UITextField                 *phoneField;
@property (weak, nonatomic       ) IBOutlet UITextField                 *insuranceField;
@property (weak, nonatomic       ) IBOutlet UITextField                 *emailField;




@property (strong                ) NSManagedObject                      *pilot;



- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;




#import "PilotViewController.h"

@interface PilotViewController ()


@end

@implementation PilotViewController
@synthesize pilot;




#pragma mark Core Data Managed Object

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate                     = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context                         = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self                            = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization



    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark Save and Cancel Buttons

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (self.pilot) {


        //Update existing pilot information

        [self.pilot setValue:self.nameField.text forKey:@"pilotName"];
        [self.pilot setValue:self.phoneField.text forKey:@"pilotPhone"];
        [self.pilot setValue:self.insuranceField.text forKey:@"pilotInsurance"];
        [self.pilot setValue:self.emailField.text forKey:@"pilotEmail"];



    } else {


        // Create a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newPilot       = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pilot" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newPilot setValue:self.nameField.text forKey:@"pilotName"];
        [newPilot setValue:self.phoneField.text forKey:@"pilotPhone"];
        [newPilot setValue:self.insuranceField.text forKey:@"pilotInsurance"];
        [newPilot setValue:self.emailField.text forKey:@"pilotEmail"];
        {
        NSString *pilotName = [pilot valueForKey:@"pilotName"];
            NSLog( @"%@",pilotName);

        //NSLog(@"Value of pilotName = %@",pilot);
            }

    NSError *error                  = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
}
@end
```

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Code "dumping" is discouraged. You should only post the code you are not sure about.

Comment: I think you mean `respondsToSelector` not `performSelector`. I doubt that will solve your problem, however.

Comment: Can we see where you set up your managed object context in your app delegate?

Comment: It is important to change to `respondsToSelector`because your app will crash if the delegate does not have that selector and you attempt to perform that selector on the delegate. You'll get one of these bad boys, `-[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance <your_instance>`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your managed object context is nil. Why are you setting it to nil in the first place? The proper way to retrieve it is to make sure you cast the app delegate to **your** app delegate:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
return delegate.manageObjectContext;
```

The pattern recommended by Apple does not use the app delegate. You should give your class a `@property` for the context and pass the context from the presenting view controller (e.g. in `prepareForSegue`).

Comment: So where I have = nil, I should have the app delegate instead?

Comment: Where are they setting the context to nil? I don't see it. They appear to be just initializing the ManagedObjectContext pointer. Additionally, it's unclear if they have even set the persistent on their managed object context.

Comment: @user3927993 No. Your question makes little sense. Maybe you are a bit over your head on this.